# Legacy code: mmap zero page: Operation not permitted - where should i start?

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, mmap

I've to deal with *old* C- Sourcecode. After I managed to compile it, while running it I get the error message

```
mmap zero page: Operation not permitted
```

Sometimes followed by an *Segmentation fault*.

I've read some stuff about the mmap() command, but I can't get around, where this error message comes from and how I should deal with it.

Can I "reenable" it? (The program used to work with an older Linux System).

I'm working with Ubuntu 11.04 and GCC 3.4

Any hints very much appreciated :-)

thanks
 Markus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mapping the zero page is disabled by default, as a security measure (doing so can make some `NULL` pointer dereference bugs exploitable).

You can re-enable it by setting the `vm.mmap_min_addr` sysctl to 0 (also available at `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr`).  You should be able to make this the default at boot on Ubuntu by adding `vm.mmap_min_addr = 0` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: perfect, seems to work like a charm :-) awesome :D tanks a lot!